# Group member cannot write into directory

Tags: debian, permissions

It seems that I have a deep misunderstanding about users and groups (I see that is sounds stupid but it's true).

The problem is down there.

- On my Debian instance, I have a couple of users and a group including these users.

  ```
  $ ls -l
  total 16
  drwxrwxr-x 4 ishakhbazyan writers 4096 Sep 14 12:49 docs
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 ishakhbazyan writers 7033 Sep 14 15:20 mkdocs.yml
  drwxrwxr-x 6 ishakhbazyan writers 4096 Sep 15 11:25 site
  ```

  (`ishakhbazyan` is my username on the system).
- Another user is a member of the `writers` group, too. This group does have write permissions to all necessary folders, but when he tries to edit any files in there (in subfolders, for example), or build documentation, he gets the `Permission denied` error.

I'm already stuck, it seems that I tried all internet advices. What can be the problem cause?

Comment: OK for the directories but what are the permissions set for the files the other member of the *writers* group wants to edit ?

Comment: Are these files on NFS?

Comment: What's the exact error message? Not just "Permission denied" but the rest of it too

Comment: @MC68020
For example
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ishakhbazyan writers 1793 Sep 15 11:25 mainpage_en.md
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ishakhbazyan writers 2316 Sep 14 15:29 partners_integration_en.md
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ishakhbazyan writers 3305 Sep 15 21:12 terms_en.md`

Comment: @roaima
No, NFS is not used
The error message is (for example):
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/koshelek/site/en/cm_check_in_api/diagrams/out/get_check_in_en.png'`

I checked the /site subfolder, and I see that rights are
`drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Sep 16 13:24 assets
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Sep 16 13:24 en
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Sep 16 13:24 ru
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 16 13:24 search`
Could it be the problem?

Comment: Almost certainly since those files do not get the write permission set for writers. However they are not the files you had said been edited by the other user. These are more likely files accessed by some script the other user is running.

Comment: Well, we use the MkDocs engine that builds documentiation into the `/var/www/koshelek/site/` directory. May it help if I change group for this directory from `root` to `writers` and make chmod -R 755 for it?